# How to get environment variables in C in a cross platform way

Tags: c++, c, cross-platform, environment-variables

I'm using the following code in OSX and in Windows Vista:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

extern char **environ;

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; environ[i] != NULL; i++)
    {
        printf("var = %s - %d\n", environ[i], (int)strlen(environ[i]));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

On OSX compile it with `cc`, on Windows - with 'cl' from Windows SDK 7.1 (with Redistributable Packages: Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 in it).

I define the same ENV variables in both OS in Russian language: MY_ENV='russian letters goes here'. And have got a difference about 2 times in a length of a strings.

This length I'm planning to use in `malloc` and want them be the same. How can I get the same lengths correctly, in CRT way?

Comment: I guess one is using UTF8 encoding and the other a local code-page?

Comment: Since the environment block is preallocated by the OS, why does it matter? If you intend to copy it to your own variable, just measure its length first and allocate enough space.

Comment: With VC you can use `wmain`, which can have a third parameter `env` which should be in UTF-16 and then you can convert to UTF-8.

Comment: What's wrong with `getenv` and `setenv`?

Comment: I'm not using VC. I'm not using `getenv` because I need all variables.

Comment: And yes, I'm trying to measure their lengths to allocate the space, and wants it works correctly cross platform. But in OSX it is OK, and in Windows it fails.

Comment: I second @DarkFalcon's comment.  The length really seems to be a non-problem.  Just get its (the argument's) length, use it to allocate space to your variable, then copy arguments to your allocated variable.

Comment: I'm porting the code, and think the problem is in strlen because of different lengths. So now I think the problem in a string copying procedures. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

- [`getenv`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html) is available on GNU/Linux, Mac OS X, and Microsoft Windows.
- [`setenv`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setenv.3.html) is available of GNU/Linux and Mac OS X but not on Microsoft Windows.
- [`putenv`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/putenv.3.html), like `getenv`, is available on GNU/Linux, Mac OS X, and Microsoft Windows.

Thus `getenv` and `putenv` are your best cross-platform options.

Comment: [This API cannot be used in applications that execute in the Windows Runtime. For more information, see CRT functions not supported in Universal Windows Platform apps.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getenv-wgetenv?view=msvc-160)