# setenv() vs. putenv() - Which one to use for cross-platform environment editing?

Tags: c, windows

I recently contributed an environment variable class to a scripting language and used `putenv(const char*)` for setting environment variables in the format of `key=value`. However, the author changed it to `setenv(const char*, const char*)` instead.

Originally, I had used the `putenv` function since it was mentioned on another SO answer, that it was the more platform-independent method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23073039/2423150

But appearently, Windows *does* have `setenv`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/putenv?view=vs-2017

So, which one should be used? The scripting language is meant to be compiled under some backwards compatibility aspects - but just how far has it been that `setenv` was introduced? The link pointing to MSDN actually mentions this POSIX function being deprecated but also that the version of documentation points at VS 2017. I am a little bit confused here...

Comment: I see no reference to `setenv` in the Microsoft page you've linked.

Comment: The whole MAN page needs to be read/understood.  In this case the statement: *This API cannot be used in applications that execute in the Windows Runtime. For more information, see CRT functions not supported in Universal Windows Platform apps.* is the critical item.

Comment: @user3629249 People don't read manpages on windows

Answer (score 1):

setenv does not exist in older compilers.  Putenv exists in all compilers that run under Microsoft operating systems that I'm aware of including ancient ones.  For Windows I would recommend putenv (or putenv_s).

putenv is used in an example here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getenv-wgetenv?view=msvc-160